# i can't delete my droplets or doing any option on my account

Tags: cloud, digital-ocean

i'm using digitalocean clouding service for my application which has no visitors yet ...

but i have noticed that for 1 month and some days they send me messages that i have to pay an unacceptable amount of money ... , 
So i decided to stop using the droplet (delete it) or recize it but i could not do anything i created a ticket and they told me that i have to pay the scales that i can not pay them to even delete my account ... Do you have any advice or suggestions? thank's a lot .

Comment: If you don't wanna pay, don't pay, they will suspend/delete your account. If you had the servers running for a month ofcourse they will ask you to pay the bill. Anyway not a question for SO, flagging to be closed.

Comment: Thank u a lot but how could i closed my server without stopping my application ?

Comment: How do you expect to keep your application running if you don't pay bills.

Comment: Depending on the droplet the lowest cost is only $5USD/Month so not sure how you have a bill for an 'unacceptable amount of money` you must pay for what you use - if the account is locked you can only contact them. If you leave it then all data will be deleted after a period but you won't get anything back...